# How to connect to Mysql using C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm just a beginner in C#. I'm using XAMPP server for MySQL database and Visual C# 2010. Then I have created a database named "testdb" in phpMyAdmin and a table named "login". I have inserted my username and password in the table. I'm doing a simple WinForm login where I made two text boxes for username and password and a button. I have my codes done and there's no compiler error. But I had troubled in one line. It says "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts". I added MySql.Data to my references. I want to fetch the data in the database table when I'm going to log in. Then authorize the user or if not matched, it will prompt an error message.

Here is my code:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient; 

public bool Login(string username, string password)
{
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=localhost;username…");
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='" +
                                      username + "' AND password='" + password + "';");

    cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open(); // This is the line producing the error.

    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if (reader.Read() != false)
    {    
        if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == true)
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            return false;
        }    
        else
        {
            cmd.Connection.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            cmd.Dispose();
            return true;
        }    
    }    
    else
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

*I hope for your your feedback. :)

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Post the entire connection string (redact the password of course)

Comment: Consider ASP.NET Dynamic Data if you are trying to produce a web interface for CRUD access to the database.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845452(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @AdamSchiavone
What is the connection string?

Comment: @user20138 its the string inside `new MySqlConnection()`

Comment: "I added MySql.Data to my references", saying this I assume you have installed "MySQL Connector/net". Can you add **MySql.DafaFC** instead of **MySql.Data**? The same thing worked for me on VS 2013 express. Also no need to use "MySql for visual studio plugin".

Comment: since your using **XAMPP** don't forget to add **MySql.Web** to your references

Answer (score 17):

Your immediate problem is probably either an incorrect connection string or the database server is not available. The connection string should be something like this

```
Server=localhost;Database=testdb;Uid=<username>;Pwd=<password>;
```

with `<username>` and `<password>` replaced with your actual values.

Besides that your code has several issues and you should definitely look into them if this is intended to become production code and probably even if this is just a toy project to learn something. The list is in particular order and may not be comprehensive.

1. Do not hard code your connection string. [Instead move it to a configuration file.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
2. Do not include plain text passwords in configuration files or source code. There are various solutions like [windows authentication, certificates](http://connectionstrings.com/mysql) or [passwords protected](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) by the [Windows Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx).
3. Do not just dispose `IDisposable` instances by calling `IDisposable.Dispose()`. [Instead use the `using` statement to release resources even in the case of exceptions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)
4. Do not build SQL statements using string manipulation techniques. [Instead use `SqlParameter` to prevent SQL injection attacks.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
5. Do not store plain text passwords in a database. [Instead at least store salted hashes of the passwords and use a slow hash function, not MD5 or a member of the SHA family.](http://www.securityfocus.com/blogs/262)
6. You can use [`IDbCommand.ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.executescalar.aspx) to retrieve a scalar result and avoid using a data reader.
7. Comparing a boolean value with `true` or `false` is redundant and just adds noise to your code. Instead of `if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == true)` you can just use `if (reader.IsDBNull(0))`. The same holds for `if (reader.Read() != false)` what is equivalent to `if (reader.Read() == true)` and therefore also `if (reader.Read())`.
8. Using an O/R mapper like the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx) is usually preferred over interacting with the database on the level of SQL commands.

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your ConnectionString accordingly to the Standard MySQL ConnectionString:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Source:
[MySQL ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

You can also take a look at the following link, that shows how to connect to a MySQL database using C#:

[Creating a Connector/Net Connection String (MYSQL)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-connection-string.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple and sql injection free, and also don't forget to add **MySql.Web**
in your references since your using **XAMPP**

```
        public bool Login(string username, string password)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string config = "server=....";
            using (var con = new MySqlConnection { ConnectionString = config })
            {
                using (var command = new MySqlCommand { Connection = con })
                {
                    con.Open();
                    command.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM login WHERE username=@username AND password=@password";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
                    dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;

                } // Close and Dispose command

            } // Close and Dispose connection
        }
```