# ASPX connect to wamp database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, wamp

I'm trying to connect aspx to a wamp database. Here's the database credentials:

```
Server: mysql_wampserver
user: sa
password: Passw0rd
computer: mypc
database: ProjetoUtilizadores
```

In my web.config i'm using the following:

```
<add key="cn" value="Server=localhost\mysql_wampserver;Database=ProjetoUtilizadores;User ID=sa;Password=Passw0rd;Trusted_Connection=False"/>
```

Whenever i try to connect i get the error "26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" any help? Thank you.

NOTE: Firewall is currently disabled on the computer that i'm using either for VisualStudio or WAMP server.

EDIT: i tried with Server=localhost and Server=MY_IP and now i get 
Named Pipes Provider, `error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL ServeR`

Comment: instead of `localhost` have you tried specifying path of `mysqld`? may be that fix it. Also do have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801948/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-c

Comment: Greetings. Where can i find that path?

Comment: If the database is located on your PC then remove the mysql_wampserver part, if the database is located on a machine named mysql_wampserver remove the localhost part. Or use the IP address of the target machine. [See here examples of MySql connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: now i'm getting error: 40 - could not open a connection to sql server

Comment: SQL Server or MySql? Please show the code that opens the connection. I have more than a feeling where the error is.

Comment: See the answer from @Steve below. At which point, your conn string would likely look like this `<add name="mySql" connectionString="server=the_server_name_or_IP;uid=user_name;database=the_db;pwd=user_pwd" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />`

Answer (score 1):

If you connect to a `MySql Server` you need to use the `MySqlConnection` class and, of course, the same MySql version of every other ADO.NET classes (MySqlCommand, MySqlDataReader, MySqlDataAdapter).

So your code should be something like this....

```
 using(MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionStringFromConfig()))
 {
     using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commandText, cnn))
     {
         cnn.Open();
         .......
     }
 }
```

These classes are available in the **MySql .Net Connector**.
The latest version could be downloaded [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.1.html), after installation you need to add a reference to this library and add a `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` directive to your project files where you use these classes.