# how to remotely access a mysql database using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, database

i am a student at computer science, i have made a project in c# that uses mysql for the database. now it's almost ready for deployment but i cant figure it out how to access the database stored on my computer from another device over the internet. i need a noob guide, what should i change?

```
string connection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=123456";
MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(connection);
```

i have used mysql workbench to manipulate the database. 
     thank you very much. and sorry for my english.

Comment: How can it almost be ready for Deployment if you cannot access the Database

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801948/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-c

Comment: The problem is that your database is located on your computer and not on a server designed to handle remote calls to the database. Either you need to do like David Soussan said, or you need to use a remotely hosted MySQL server, and connect to that one. -1 because this is something you should have been thought on your computer science studies, or should have read up on before using SQL for remote calls.

Comment: i can access it from my laptop and it works flawless all that i need now is to access it from another laptop. sorry maybe i am a little to rushed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a static IP address for your internet connection.
2. Open port 3306 on your firewall.
3. Change the datasource in the connection string to the IP address of your internet connection.